# Ionic 1: Gulpfile error - 'labsass' bindings not found

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, gulp, gulp-sass

I get this error.

```
There is an error in your gulpfile: 
Error: `libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?
at getBinding (/Users/SubjectiveEffect/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:22:11)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/SubjectiveEffect/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:188:23)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

I've reinstalled node-sass, npm, node, ionic, everything.

Any idea what is going on? I see that a lot of people have problems with this but there seem to be no solutions...

Ionic serve doesn't work anymore because of this. App is almost ready for release but...

My gulfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var bower = require('bower');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sh = require('shelljs');

var paths = {
  sass: ['./scss/**/*.scss']
};

gulp.task('default', ['sass']);

gulp.task('sass', function(done) {
  gulp.src('./scss/ionic.app.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .pipe(minifyCss({
      keepSpecialComments: 0
    }))
    .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .on('end', done);
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.sass, ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('install', ['git-check'], function() {
  return bower.commands.install()
    .on('log', function(data) {
      gutil.log('bower', gutil.colors.cyan(data.id), data.message);
    });
});

gulp.task('git-check', function(done) {
  if (!sh.which('git')) {
    console.log(
      '  ' + gutil.colors.red('Git is not installed.'),
      '\n  Git, the version control system, is required to download Ionic.',
      '\n  Download git here:', gutil.colors.cyan('http://git-scm.com/downloads') + '.',
      '\n  Once git is installed, run \'' + gutil.colors.cyan('gulp install') + '\' again.'
    );
    process.exit(1);
  }
  done();
});
```

Comment: Post your **gulpfile.js**

Comment: I've added it now.

Comment: Have you recently downgraded/upgraded Node?

Comment: Yes. I just updated it.

Comment: Try running `npm update` inside your dir. Or just `npm remove gulp-sass` and then `npm install gulp-sass --save-dev`

Comment: I've tried this. I've sudo tried it. I get some errors, including a Build Error at one point. I get "module.js: 471" throw error.